# Write text from parent page into an iframe textbox

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe

I have written an email program in php file and loaded into iframe to display in .tpl file.

I just want to write email id into the sender textbox. The email id is displayed in parent page within a div and span also.

```
<div id="aff_details" style="display:none;">
<span id="aff_email">{$username}</span>
<span id="aff_url">{$data1}</span>
</div>
```

I just want to display the aff_email into the below textbox which in an iframe.

```
<input type="text" name="sender" value="" class="TextBox" id="sender">
```

Now, I am using

```
 $('iframe#sender').html($('div#aff_details span#aff_email').text());
```

But, It is not displaying anything in the textbox.

Could anyone please help me out.

Comment: Try replacing .html() with .text() or with .value()

Comment: where is the iframe code?

Comment: @Sudharsan, the input box is in iframe. its like <main page><div id="aff_details" style="display:none;">
<span id="aff_email">{$username}</span>
<span id="aff_url">{$data1}</span> 
</div><iframe src="file.php"></iframe></mainpage>.